# Angular - freezes first tab until the another tab is fully loaded

Tags: javascript, angular, browser, angular7

we have a working app in Angular 7. Application speed pretty good but sometimes application screen is frozen like below scenarios;

**I have one tab** and there is also a button on the page. The purpose of this button is to open any page **in a new tab.** (with `window.open(url, '_blank')`)

I click the button to open the new tab. And then my first tab freezes until the new tab is fully loaded. 
I can't click on anything in the first tab. For example, **I click the selectbox in the first tab. Then the selectbox does not open until the new tab is fully loaded.**

*A small note: Of course, this has nothing to do with the button and the `window.open` code. For example, I have two tab. I pressed to f5 for the second tab and I switched to the first tab. The same problem again. I can't click to anything in the first tab until the second tab is fully loaded.*

*Another small note: I've tried with Chrome, Firefox, Opera. And in they all have the same problem.*

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because the new window is opened in the same process with the opener window.

```
window.open(url,'_blank','noopener')
```